# Prove for some finite $k$, $f^k(n)=1 \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, induction, dynamical-systems

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ defined as $$f(n)=n+1$$ if $n$ is composite or 2. $$f(n)=\frac{n-1}{2}$$ if $n$ is prime.
Prove that for some finite $k$ $f^k(n)=1$, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is $k{}{}$?

Comment: Who is $k$ and what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the question you are trying to ask is this:

> Consider a function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ defined as $$
> \begin{cases}f(n)=n+1 & n\text{ is composite or } n=2\\
> f(n) = \frac{n-1}{2} & n \text{ is prime.}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Prove that **for every $n$, there exists an integer $k$ such that** $f^k(n)=1$, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

If this is the question, then here is a hint: use the [Bertrand-Chebyshev theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate).